# Iphone resource file size limit

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Is there any file size limitation for iphone resource file.For example my sqllite db size can larger than 300 mb?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there is a limitation, but you might annoy people if you store 300mb of database on their iphone! can you not store it on the internet and use XML or JSON or something?

Comment: Have you thought of testing with a 300Mb sqlite database and answering your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the iOS file system is truly a variation of the Mac file system, the answer is 2 Gigabytes or limited-by-flash-size.

The older Macintosh file systems had a 2 Gigabyte limit for files (32-bits counting 512-byte blocks), but this was increased dramatically by an upgrade at some point.  I think it changed the counter to 64-bits. Whatever the details, a file probably easily exceeds any amount of flash Apple cares to put into a device.

If memory serves, iOS devices are formatted with 2 partitions.  One for the iOS, the other for everything else.  So at least you won't make the device fail by filling the drive.  (Macs get sluggish and hard to use when full.)

Practically speaking, developers mostly worry about the 20-Megabyte application size limit imposed by iOS for downloading over cellular networks.  Many apps go beyond this and require a wifi connection to download (or download to iTunes on desktop.)

Apple does not limit the size of apps in the App Store.  I have worked on apps that weigh in over 300 Megabytes and they still ship free.  The elements app measures in Gigabytes, probably due to huge media files.